# rewrite URL based on selected taxonomy for post page

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a taxonomy called "group",  and their values like "red", "blue", "green" (these are generating dynamic" no any fixed group value.

during post publish I am selecting "**Group**" for each post. 1 group for each post.

I want to add a rewrite URL for the post if the taxonomy is "red" or "blue" or "green" then the URL of that post should come like

`"myweb.com/red/post-slug-name"` or `"myweb.com/green/post-slug-name"` or `"myweb.com/blue/post-slug-name"` ...

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_group_tax' );
function create_group_tax() {
    register_taxonomy( 
            'group', 
            'post', 
             array( 'label' => 'Group', 
                    'hierarchical' => true
                )
        );
}

add_rewrite_rule('^red/([^/]*)/?','index.php?group=$matches[1]','top');
```

also, I want to make it regex rule "`'^red/([^/]*)/?'`"  dynamic with selected taxonomy,this time just to make a test i added it as a static string.

result : **Page not found. Nothing here  - http://localhost/wordpress/red/my-test/**

what do you suggest to do this?